# Trigger not activating in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the scene to switch when a method in the script `TrippleBall` returns 0. I know it returns 0 at the appropriate time because I have tested it. Here is my code to switch scenes:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "ball")
    {
        col.gameObject.GetComponent<Ball>().setIsOffScreen(true);
      /*error*/ if (GameObject.Find("TrippleBalls").GetComponent<TripleBall>().getBallCount() == 0) {

            Debug.Log("Loading next screen...");
            SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOverScene");
        }

    }

}
```

Here is an image to show where `TrippleBalls` is

[image]

The script `TrippleBall` is in the component `TrippleBalls`

Here is an image to show where the code above is located.

[image]

The code above is in a class called `SceneTrigger` which has been put in `LBackBoard` and `RBackBoard`

When I test the code, and the `getBallCount` returns 0 (to satisfy the condition above) I get the following error:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

This error line sends me to where i marked `error` in the code above.

If anyone can help me figure this out, that would be awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You GameObject is named `TrippleBall` in the Scene but you are looking for `TrippleBalls` in the Scene. Simply change `GameObject.Find("TrippleBalls")` to `GameObject.Find("TrippleBall");`.

Also Don't use GameObject.Find in the OnTrigger function. It will slow down your game.Cach TripleBall in a local variable then you can re-use it.

```
TripleBall myTripleBall = null;

void Strt(){
//Cache TripleBall
myTripleBall = GameObject.Find("TrippleBalls").GetComponent<TripleBall>()
}
```

Now you can re-use it any time.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "ball")
    {
        Debug.Log("COUNT IS: "+myTripleBall.getBallCount());
        col.gameObject.GetComponent<Ball>().setIsOffScreen(true);
        if (myTripleBall.getBallCount() == 0) {

            Debug.Log("Loading next screen...");
            SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOverScene");
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to Add the **GameOverScene** scene in your Build Setting.
[image]

**Advice**:
Advice for you is that when Looking for another GameObject inside another GameObject, Use '/' like you would in a folder path. For example, TrippleBall is under Specialties GameObject. So use `GameObject.Find("Specialties/TrippleBall");` instead of `GameObject.Find("TrippleBall");`

Comment: the error is gone but it still didnt print or change scenes

Comment: @Luke Make sure to Add the GameOverScene scene in your Build Setting.

Comment: I did all of this and it still didn't work. I even tested just loading the next scene and that worked.

Comment: @Luke I updated my answer. If it doesn't print **Loading next screen** then `getBallCount()` is NOT returning 0.

Comment: Does it print "Loading next screen"?

Comment: No, nothing at all

Comment: @Luke Your getBallCount() function is not returning 0. That's why. Please fix it. This solution will solve your  error but not your bad game logic code. getBallCount() is is not doing what you think it is doing and I don't know what code it contains. That's the problem you are having now.

Comment: I tested it by printing("called") before returning the int and it was called. I also tested it within the class it is in. I put in the update method ` if(getBallCount() == 0)
print("yes"); ` and it worked. it has to be me not getting the GameObject correct or something. Which is the initial question

Comment: @Luke If **Loading next screen** doesn't show, the condition is `false` which that that function is not returning 0. This also means that the level will **never** load since level loads when that function returns 0. It is not magic. It is a fact.

Comment: @Luke To verify what I just said, update your code with my updated answer. You will see a message **COUNT IS:** some number. That number is never 0. Try it.

Comment: The problem isn't solved with this. I did this a couple minutes ago and it returns one. However, since this pushes me in the direction I need to be in, it solves the problem asked. Thanks a ton, you're a life saver.

Comment: @Luke You are welcome. If you still can't solve the problem, you can create a new post and actually post the `getBallCount()` function. Without it no one can help you. Explain what it does in that question and ask why it does not return 0.

Comment: In case you're curious. It was always returning 1, but only because it checked the collionEnter right before it was destroyed. No one could of known but me. Thanks!

Comment: @Luke Lol Of-course I knew if it was returning something other than 0. I just didn't know why because I don't know what the function looks like. Glad you found out why. Anyways, good luck with your game.